# Extending Magento REST API

Tags: api, rest, magento, extend

I could not find anything on the internet, so I hope someone here has an awnser to my question.

Is it possible to extend the REST API for Magento and if so, does someone have an example or guide on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Magento REST Api can indeed be extended.  There is a blog post on my website showing how to make a start on doing this http://web.archive.org/web/20130512072025/http://magepim.com/news/Extending-the-Magento-REST-API-part-1_13

It only covers the basic setup but hopefully it'll give you a starting point.

Comment: The api.xml in this example won't be needed for REST. This is for SOAP/XML-RPC.

Comment: I was created custom rest api for category but returns 403(Access denied) error when use host url but it completely working using RESTClient firefox extension.

Comment: That link is dead, but fortunatly I found a cached version on archive.org. If anyone else is looking for it, here is the link: http://web.archive.org/web/20130512072025/http://magepim.com/news/Extending-the-Magento-REST-API-part-1_13

Comment: @JohanFalk
how to call other function of v1.php file, or what changes required in xml file for calling create or update function ....?
Kindly answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224378/extend-magento-rest-api-in-custom-module

Thanks

Comment: Site is dead due to a server outage that I haven't had time to rebuild but will be back soon.  Thanks for posting the web archive link.